# Проверка Логина и Пароля

Tags: php

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "vladon12";
$db_name = "cdcol";
$tbl_name = "members";

mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die("can't connect");
mysql_select_db($db_name) or die(mysql_error());
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1) {
  session_register("username");
  session_register("password");
  header("location:login_success.php");
}
else{  
echo "Неверный Логин или Пароль";
}

?>
```

Вот что здесь не верно, оно мне пишет "Неверный Логин или Пароль" Даже если пароль и Логин верны, что делать? Заранее спасибо)

Comment: после **`$count = mysql_num_rows($result);`** сделайте **`die(var_dump($count, mysql_fetch_array($result), $username, $password, mysql_error()));`**, что выведет?

Comment: У Вас точно в таблице одна такая запись с логин/паролем? Сколько mysql_num_rows возвращает?

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";` — никогда так не делайте. И вообще, не занимайтесь некрофилией с `mysql_*` (они уже deprecated) — возьмите, наконец, PDO. Или PEAR::DB, на худой конец.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У тебя в коде две переменных ссылаются на одно имя $username

Answer (score 0):

Код отлично работает. Варианта 2:

1. что-то не то передается в `$_POST['username']` или `$_POST['password']`
2. или в таблице "members" косяк. Кстати, можно ее дамп посмотреть?

Answer (score 0):

может пароль в md5 в базе хранится?

Answer (score 0):

```
....
if(mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT count(*) FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'" LIMIT 1),0)==1)
{
    session_register("username");
    session_register("password");
    header("location:login_success.php");
} else {
    echo "Неверный Логин или Пароль";
}
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Может не то соединение? Указывай его жестко.

Может не `$_POST`?

Может в логине-пароле есть знак `'`

Может стоит обрезать пробелы, `\r` и `\n` у логина и пароля?

А может имя таблицы неверно указано или какие-то не те символы где-то вылазят? Стоит [спросить у самого мускула об ошибке](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-error.php)?

```
<?

// ...

error_reporting(E_ALL);

$DB = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die("can't connect");
mysql_select_db($db_name, $DB) or die(mysql_error());

$username = $_POST['username'];  // точно не $_GET?
$password = $_POST['password'];  // точно не $_GET?

$username = trim($username);
$password = trim($password);

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username, $DB);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password, $DB);

var_dump($username, $password);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `" .$tbl_name. "` WHERE username='" .$username. "' and password='". $password. "'";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $DB);

echo '<pre>'.$sql.'</pre><p>'.mysql_error($DB).'</p>';

// ...

?>
```